# How to make a cell dynamically display an average % according to chosen time period?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-query-language, sparklines

I want this cell to output the average value according to the time period chosen.
If I choose 7 days, the cell should display the average value for the last week / 7 days.
If I choose 6 months, it displays the average of the last 6 months and so on. Is this possible?

Link for editable file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change B14 to:

```
=INDEX(SPARKLINE(QUERY({IFERROR(DATEVALUE(HISTORY!A:A)), HISTORY!D:D}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col1 <= "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A))&"
    and Col1 >  "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A))-C12-1, 0),
 {"charttype","line";"color","#1aded1"}))
```

and for average use in C13:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(QUERY({IFERROR(DATEVALUE(HISTORY!A:A)), HISTORY!D:D}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col1 <= "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A))&"
    and Col1 >  "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A))-C12-1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: @verminous if answer helped you and solved your issue, please accept it by checking the mark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDBGo.png